# How do I get the address of my user's gallery images?

Tags: react-native

How can I get all the images from the user's gallery and display them like this, as in the example, within a screen of my app? I've tried using the lib react native cameraroll, but I haven't found a method that might look similar.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI0nn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);

CameraRoll.getPhotos({
    first: 50,
    assetType: 'Photos',
  })
  .then(res => {
    setPhotos(res.edges);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
  });
```

Now you have the first 50 photos in the phone stored as a state.

Then you have to show them in a `FlatList`. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wv0kjsirso&t=1s) might help you with that.

Also check [this](https://reactnativeforyou.com/how-to-show-photos-of-your-device-as-a-gallery-in-react-native/) out, it also might help you with the whole thing including the `CameraRoll` implementation.